# Fix for 'bytes missing in capture file' using rawcap?

Tags: tcp, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packet-loss

I am using [rawcap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) tcp capture tool for capturing localhost packets on windows.

I have a huge stream flowing and there are multiple

> 'XXXX bytes missing in the capture file'

in the captured file.

How can I prevent this? How can I capture the complete TCP packet from localhost?

Is there any other tool which I can use?

Thanks